# "all demographic information" or "all the demographic information"

Tags: grammar

The sentence I wrote is

"Please answer to the questions and complete **all the demographic information** / **all demographic information**".

Which one is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given context I assume the reader knows what demographic information you are referring to, so **all the demographic information** is better.

Also, "answer" is a verb so it should be "answer the questions" without the "to". As a verb phrase, "answer to" usually means "be responsible to".

Comment: Thank you for an additional information. Then I should say, "Please answer the questions and complete all the demographic information."